# Different IP address error?

Tags: ip, wifi, router

I had connect my laptop and phone under a same router/modem.
But the IP addresses that shown on my laptop and phone are different, why???
I'm quite newbie for it, please help me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming in any way. Also it lacks basic understanding of the issue at hand

Comment: I'm quite newbie in this field, so sorry

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are different inside your network. When you send data outside the network your router uses NAT (Network Address Translation) to assign your Internal(LAN) address your External(WAN) address for the duration of that communication. If they had the same Internal IP address then you would have an error like this http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/f/ip_conflict.htm

Comment: how to connect them together as the ip addresess are different?

Comment: if they're connected to the same router they're in the same network and can communicate with each other

Comment: I did connected them together, but the data can't sent